# Custom CSS for Squarespace Calendar color change

Tags: css, calendar, background-color, squarespace

I simply want to change the background color for a calendar block in squarespace. It's overtop an index image and I need to be opaque black. I've tried several codes but can't figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: Not getting what you exactly want? Please explain in brief.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following CSS, inserted via [Custom CSS](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545567-Using-the-CSS-Editor) will:

- Target a specific calendar block via its block ID
- Add a black background to the block
- Add padding to the top of the block so that the title isn't right up against the black background color

```
#block-cc09bdbd4987547c1c3f {
  background-color: black;
  padding-top: 17px;
}
```

You might also consider creating some visual definition to the days of the month via:

```
#block-cc09bdbd4987547c1c3f .yui3-calendar-day {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

Comment: That worked! Hadn't thought to just do the block... thank you. And the grid looks good with that definition too, thanks again!